# Any way to select IP address for outgoing connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I am creating a web app and I need to select the IP address for outgoing connection (or it chooses a randomly changing one automatically - GoDaddy shared hosting (but I have a dedicated IP too with that hosting for incoming connections, which I should be able to use for outgoing connections too, obviously)). How can I enumerate Network adapters and choose the one to use with WebRequests, TcpClients etc. ?

Thanks,
Can.

Comment: It seems like this should be an OS setting (and setting up the "default gateway"  appropriately)?

Comment: i am on shared hosting without access to OS. my app is running under medium trust. but i have a dedicated ip assigned for incoming connections, and i'm searching for a way to use this for outgoing connections too which should technically be possible

Comment: I strongly suspect that your "should be able to use for outgoing connections too" statement is wrong. Server your code runs at may (=likely) not have this IP at all as the IP handled by externally facing routers directing traffic to internal servers (some sort of NAT configuration).

Comment: so, what I'm trying to achieve is not possible with my current config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted GoDaddy about this issue. It turned out as it's not possible in a shared hosting environment (even with a dedicated IP).

Answer (score 1):

Even if your socket is not going to Listen(), You could still use bind to assign the local address.

[For example for TcpClient it can be specified using the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx)

If you do need to bind, just specify the local address in the paramaters.

Comment: actually I need a default setting somewhere, as I'm using the Facebook C# SDK and even though I am sure internally it uses a Tcp/Http/Web Client, I don't have access to its constructor or there isn't any method for specifying IPEndPoint or network adapter

Comment: Primary address for outbound connections is defined by the minimum `Metric` of the specific routes to the destination ip in the operating system.
If you could change metric values for the default gw/ network adapter, you could change the source address. 
Note that it would affect all other connections as well.

I'm pretty positive, tough, that doing this specifically for the use of the SDK, is not possible using conventional methods if the API does not expose any binding option.